# unable to copy 2015,2016,2017 to values property of 2015,2016,2017 of arr

Tags: javascript

I tried to copy 2015,2016,2017 to values property of value of 2015,2016,2017 of respected year

expected output as below

arr = [{2015:1,2016:2,2017:3, values: [{id: "111",year: 2015,value:1},{id: "991",year: 2016,value: 2},{id: "123",year: 2017,value: 3}]}];

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
let arr = [{2015:1,2016:2,2017:3, values: [{id: "111",year: 2015,value:20},{id: "991",year: 2016,value: 40},{id: "123",year: 2017,value: 60}]}];

console.log("---arr--before", arr)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].values.length; j++) {
        arr[i].values[j].value = arr[i][2015];
        arr[i].values[j].value = arr[i][2016];
         arr[i].values[j].value = arr[i][2017];
      }
    }

console.log("---data--after", arr)
```

Comment: can you properly describe what is your expected output?

Comment: updated the expected output

Comment: you don't need to use loop in this case

Comment: outside or inside loop

Comment: arr having multiple object

Comment: your expected output is same as your input array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I will play...

After major changes to the question here's a solution:

```js
let arr = [{2015:1,2016:2,2017:3, values: [{year: 2015,value:20},{year: 2016,value: 40},{year: 2017,value: 60}]}];


console.log("---arr--before", arr)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].values.length; j++) {
    propName = arr[i].values[j].year;
    arr[i].values[j].value = arr[i][propName];
  }
}    


console.log("---arr--after", arr)
```

Comment: You changed your question now so that there is no change from the original array.

Comment: Updated to match the revised input/output

Answer (score 0):

I leave you two options, it depends on how you are going to work the object will come better one or the other.

You were missing the loop that reads y2015

```js
let arr = [{y2015:1,y2016:2,y2017:3, values: [{y2015:20},{y2016: 40},{y2017: 60}]}];
console.log("---arr--before", arr)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].values.length; j++) { 
          let k = Object.keys( arr[i].values[j] )[0];
          arr[i].values[j][k] = arr[i][k];
  
        
      }
    }

console.log("---arr--after", arr);



let arr2 = [{y2015:5,y2016:6,y2017:7, values: {y2015:50, y2016: 60, y2017: 70}}];

console.log("---arr--before2", arr2);
for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        for (let j in arr2[i].values){
          arr2[i].values[j] = arr2[i][j];
      }
    }
console.log("---arr--after2", arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [{2015:1,2016:2,2017:3, values: [{id: "111",year: 2015,value:20},{id: "991",year: 2016,value: 40},{id: "123",year: 2017,value: 60}]}];

console.log("---arr--before", arr)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].values.length; j++) {
         arr[i].values[j].value = arr[i][Object.keys(arr[i])[j]];
    }
 }

console.log("---arr--after", arr)
```